# Angular 2 load data once and filter Observable locally

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have an angular 2 app and I've managed to set up an input on my page with an autocomplete that calls out to an api and does sever side filtering and returning of values. A lot like the tutorial found here.

Now, I'm trying a few more inputs to my page, but I don't need to filter those on the server side. That would be inefficient. Better to just get all the values when my component loads and then filter in the component. This is causing me no shortage of problems. I have an api call that returns 3 string arrays I need. I am getting those from an Angular service using the standard method like so:

```
getFormFilters(): Observable<FormFilterModel> {
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl+this.getFormFiltersPath)
      .map(res => res.json() as FormFilterModel);
  }
```

The model:

```
export interface FormFilterModel {
    array1: string[];
    array2: string[];
    array3: string[];
}
```

This works fine, and I get my observable back. Where I'm stuck is how do I now filter these 3 arrays locally? I have my inputs wired up to my form controls just like I do with the server side filtering input. I can't figure out how to get to the actual arrays in my Observable to filter them. Here's where I'm at with that code:

```
this.filteredArray1$ = this.searchForm.controls.array1Search.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => //some filtering here of formFilterModel$ to return a subset of array1 based on input)
```

I can filter an array via RegExp just fine, but getting to the actual array in the observable is something I just can't seem to do.

Comment: you can use Let.  check out this article came out this week!  https://netbasal.com/take-advantage-of-the-let-operator-in-angular-d351fd4bd1d9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to your api call an store the result in the component. Then, filter the arrays in `valuesChanges.map`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getFormFilters().subscribe(formFilters => {
    this.formFilters = formFilters;
  });

  this.filteredArray1$ =  this.searchForm.controls.array1Search.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(300)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .map(search => this.formFilters.array1.filter(value => matches(value, search)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to subscribe to the response and then filtered the object that is recieved.

```
 formfilterData :FormfilterModel;
 filteredArray1:stringp[]=[];
 this.serviceOb.getFormFilters().subscribe((formfilterData)=>{
    this.formfilterData=formfilterData;


  });
   this.formfilterData.array1.filter((data)=>{

    this.formfilterData.push(data);
    })
```